Is there any type defined in Standard Library which has copy constructor but doesn't have a move constructor?
In general, the C++ Standard Library types are designed with both copy and move semantics in mind.
Is there any type defined in the Standard Library which has a copy constructor but doesn't have a move constructor?

A copy c'tor can always be used with a rvalue argument if there is no move c'tor defined. In fact, a move c'tor will need to be explicitly deleted for a type to not work in a context that involves moving. If this is the sort of thing you have in mind, I can't say I know of any such type in the standard library... or at all, to be honest.

std::allocator has a copy constructor but doesn't have a move constructor.

I tried to find such a type in the standard. It turns out there isn't one because it doesn't make sense.

@AykhanHagverdili Why there is no move ctor for allocator ? How do you think about it?

Yes, there are classes in the standard library with a copy constructor but without a move constructor.
As Aykhan Hagverdili commented above std::allocator is an example for such a class.
But note that a lack of move constructor does not mean that the object cannot be used as an rvalue.
It simply means that the copy constructor will be used in this case.
In a way you can consider a move constuctor as simply an optimization for that case, which can always fallback to copying.
In order to prohibit using it as an ravalue, the move constructor would need to be explicitly deleted.
I am not aware of any standard library class that has a copy constructor and a deleted move constrcutor.

Why not define a move ctor for allocator?

@john I am not sure. Maybe it was considered lightweight enough so that the fallback to copy is almost like move. Or maybe it was just missed and will be changed in future versions. In any case I assume that it didn't bother anybody so far too much.

std::allocator is an empty class, I don't understand why it has a custom copy constructor in the first place.

@HolyBlackCat makes sense. And "empty" is as lightweight as can be..

@HolyBlackCat How do you draw such conclusion(i.e. std::allocator is an empty class)? I can't see such information on std::allocator indeed.

@John https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator "The default allocator is stateless"

@HolyBlackCat I can't see any relation between the allocator is stateless and the allocator is empty. Could you please explain that in details for me?

@John Are you arguing that the standard doesn't require it to be empty? Or is it an honest question? It's empty in all implementations I know of, since all it does is calling new/delete (and doing so doesn't require any member variables). "Stateless" and "empty" are usually synonymous.

@John Note that the Standard uses different wording. default.allocator.general/2 requires allocator_traits<allocator<T>>​::​is_always_equal​::​value to be true, which means that, according to allocator.traits.types/10, is_empty<allocator<T>> is true. In summary, std::allocator<T> is empty according to this trait, which effectively means that it is "stateless" (see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/type.traits#tab:meta.unary.prop).

...The logic is clear — a class object without any subobjects cannot have a state. But, also note that this discussion is completely off-topic regarding your question.

Yes, there are such types. An example can be std::span<T> or std::string_view classes. They both have a user-declared copy constructor (defined as defaulted), which avoids implicit declaration of a move constructor.
Why don't these classes have move constructor? Simply because having it wouldn't make any sense. Note that both are required to be trivially copyable (string_view since C++23). This implies that even if they had a move constructor, it would be trivial. And trivial move constructors perform bitwise copy, same as trivial copy constructors.
Even if these classes wouldn't be required to be trivially copyable, providing non-trivial move constructor wouldn't make any sense. Their objects do not own anything, and requiring them to get into an "empty state" after move would actually make moves more expensive than copies.

You mean user-declared copy constructor (defined as defaulted) prevents implicit declaration of a move constructor?

@John Yes; see class.copy.ctor/8
